# Getting a .dep file to work on Windows server 2008 R2

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am working on a dashboard related project using the MS BI stack integrated with SharePoint.  I have a configured POC server running on Windows Server 2008 R2, SQL 2012 and SharePoint 2010.  I am trying to run one of the MS tutorials that I have already completed on the MS virtual labs in a completely 2008 environment but doing so within my SQL 2012 / SharePoint 2010 environment and this requires I use the .dep file to set the tutorial up.  When I first tried to run it I got the windows doesn't know which program to run it with but since the server is in a sandboxed area without net access it cannot search the web for the correct program.  In the tutorial it mentioned the file ran via the command prompt so I tried opening it with that and unfortunately nothing happened, but I forgot to untick the always associate box so basically I now have two issues.

First is getting the .dep file back to having no default associated program to run with or finding out what actually is the correct one and the second is to actually get the required files I need to run the .dep file and set-up the environment for the tutorial.  Unfortunately MS does not have a nicely detailed list on this.

I have tried using GPMC.MMC to remove the file association but as it is connected to our active directory the default features do not match up with what the technet article states on doing this and I don't want to cause errors on our active directory.  Any advice on how to get this working would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try downloading the offline training kit.

This training kit should contain a folder with the name "assets". Into this folder you can find an installation of the software "DependencyChecker.msi". Just do this installation. The installation associates the .dep files with the "Dependency Checker Tool"

Secondarily, you can google around to find "How to install the Microsoft Dependency Checker Tool".

In the next link Microsoft talks about the tool.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/identitytrainingcourse_silverligthandidentity2010.aspx